# Kusto Query, selecting an interval of 5 minutes and calculate the average

Tags: performance, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

I'm fairly new to the Kusto Query language so perhaps this is something very common, but I really can't find my answer. So here goes.

I've enabled performance gathering with Azure Log Analytics on some of our servers and would like to achieve the following:

From the Perf dataset, select all the CPU data from the previous day and display the average CPU utilization per 5 minutes. Now I've figured out the first part, which was really easy to do. However I can't figure out how to do the per 5 minute selection in Kusto. I'm guessing something with summarise? Can anyone share some insights?

```
Perf
| where Computer == "servername.domain.internal"
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d) 
| where CounterName == "% Processor Time" 
| where ObjectName == "Processor Information"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try adding `| summarize avg(CounterValue) by bin(Time Generated, 5m)` to your query.

For charting, you can also append a `| render timechart` to the latter.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the info!